# Running Executable Bash Script Yields "Command Not Found"

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a bash script called "myScript.bash" with:

```
#!/bin/bash

( sleep 30 && /usr/local/bin/php /home/scripts/misc/code.php ) &
( sleep 60 && /usr/local/bin/php /home/scripts/misc/code.php )
```

I then do the following to make the bash script executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/myScript.bash
```

It should run "code.php" every 30 seconds when I enter the following in the CLI:

```
myScript.bash
```

Instead, I get:

```
-bash: myScript.bash: command not found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes. Even if I run it with the full directory I still get the error

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/myScript.bash` say?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely means that your current working directory isn't in the PATH (and that's a good thing).

Try:

```
./myScript.bash
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a script you have made executable, you have to write the entire path to run it, i.e.

```
/path/to/script
```

If you only write

```
script
```

bash will search in `PATH` a file called `script`. Roughly, `PATH` is a list of directories where bash will search automatically files. Try

```
echo $PATH
```

If you open the terminal in the directory where `script` is, you may also write

```
./script
```